# How to get correct movement direction vector depending on surface

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, direction

So I'm trying to code my own third person character controller and I'm trying to find a way to calculate direction vector depending on contact surface normal and player's direction vector (transform.forward)
[image: Vectors]
I've attached image so it's more clear

Comment: I you need planar forward vector; Use `var projected = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(transform.forward, hit.normal);` Now projected is your requested vector to see: `Debug.DrawRay(hit.point, projected, Color.red);`

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer I want to ask why do you need this vector? What are you trying to do with it?

In the meantime, here is one way to do it:

1. Raycast from the player's position downwards `Physics.Raycast(player.transform.position, Vector3.Down, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, groundLayerMask)` (Maybe raycast from the middle of the player to make sure you don't miss the ground)
2. If you don't get a hit, this means that from the position of the player, there is no ground (thus, no vector to calculate)
3. If you do get a hit, it will contain a `hit.normal`, which you can then multiply by  `Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0)` - This in effect will rotate the normal of the ground by 90 degrees on the X axis, getting the normalized vector you are looking for

Comment: Instead of rotating you could use `Vector3.Cross` in order to get perpendicular vectors

Comment: @derHugo not sure if using cross will give him the normal he is looking for, plus rotating is more efficient in the math operations used compared to cross

Comment: Since Player object uses rb.MovePosition (transform.position + transform.forward * Time.fixedDeltaTime * playerSpeed); to move around and OnCollisionStay() to detect if it's grounded. So the problem here is that moving downhill, player goes fast enough to slide over and loose contact with ground making jumps glitchy. And I thought I could fix that by not moving with transform.forward, but instead a vector which is parallel with the walking surface.

Comment: @ArvisPuķītis - is there any specific reason you are using `MovePosition` and not adding to the velocity of the rigidbody? This way you will get this behavior out of the box taking into account velocity, drag, gravity, external forces, etc.


Also, if I answered your question please mark this answer as the solution, thanks

Comment: Well, I'm trying to achive snappy and quick movement and I had read that setting rigidbody velocity directly is not a good idea! rb.velocity = transform.forward * playerSpeed; is still losing contact with ground. I will mark the answers once I get it working! I guess I could use the raycast, but I think that can also miss the ground under specific conditions (for example standing at the edge of the hill).